# How can I access the second to last child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to access the second to last `li`. I tried following code, but it isn't working:

```
$('ul#selectTheme li:last').eq(-1).addClass('selected');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `ul#selectTheme li:last` selects just a single `li` (the last one), and calling `eq(-1)` will just again return that single `li` (the last one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [`:nth-last-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/):

```
$('ul#selectTheme li:nth-last-child(2)').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can simply pass a minus number to `.eq()` to get the nth element from the end. -1 being the last element and so forth.

```
$('ul#selectTheme li').eq(-2).addClass('selected');
```

Take a look here for more details - [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 1):

Just using `prev()` should suffice:

```
$('ul#selectTheme li:last').prev('li').addClass('selected');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7DhS/1/)

Comment: This assumes that all of the `ul`'s children are `li`s, which _should_ be the case, but sadly isn't always true.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the length property to get this:

```
var themes = $('#selectTheme li');
$(themes[themes.length - 2]).addClass('selected');
```

This has the added benefit of not using any of the slower jQuery pseudoselectors.

I have also omitted the `ul` part of the selector, since this unnecessary - the id selector is specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul#selectTheme li').eq(-2).addClass('selected');
```

Your case seems much like one of the examples given in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/eq/